# How to get the last Elasticsearch document for each unique value of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data structure in Elasticsearch that looks like:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "date": "2022-10-08T21:30:40.000Z",
  "rank": 3
}
```

I want to get, for each unique name, the rank of the document (or the whole document) with the most recent date.

I currently have this:

```
"aggs": {
  "group-by-name": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "name"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "max-date": {
        "max": {
          "field": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the rank (or the whole document) for each result, and if possible, in 1 request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below options

1. [Collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)

```
"collapse": {
    "field": "name"         
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": { 
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```

2. [Top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group-by-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],            
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Collapse is what I was searching for, however I need to get the result for all unique name (there are millions of uniques names) and [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/scroll-api.html) is not allowed in a [Collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) context. Is there a way to do it properly?

Comment: Collapse does not work in scroll context. Field collapsing can be used with the search_after parameter but it is only supported when sorting and collapsing on the same field. If  you are having performance issues then doing it in client side might be good idea. Elastic search works best when data is preprocessed. You can think of creating separate index for unique records or creating a single document per name , using nested field for same user.